# Converting .live() to .on() after upgrading to JQuery-1.7.1 did not fix this function

Tags: jquery

While I was using JQuery-1.6.1 for my app, I had the following line of code:

```
$('li.step .step_type.VerifyTableContentsStep input[name*=element_name]').live('autocompletechange', buildTableContents);
```

After I upgraded to JQuery-1.7.1, that line stopped working. I read in the documentation that .live() was deprecated and to use .on() instead. I tried that and, following the documentation, changed the line so that it is now like this:

```
$(document).on('autocompletechange', 'li.step .step_type.VerifyTableContentsStep input[name*=element_name]', buildTableContents);
```

But it still does not work. Does anyone have any ideas? I followed the documentation to the letter. Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is my .haml code:

```
.table_contents_container
  = select_tag :add_column, options_for_select(table_contents.headers_without_data.unshift(['hidden columns...'])), :class => 'add_column_selector'

  %table

    %tr
      %th.action_column
        = link_to '', '#', :class => 'sub_item_action add_column', :tabindex => 999
      - table_contents.rows.first.all_cells.each do |cells|
        %th.content_column{ :class => "#{'no_data' if cells.no_data?}", 'data-column-id' => cells.id }
          = link_to '', '#', :class => 'sub_item_action inline_delete', :tabindex => 999
          %span= cells.name
      %th &nbsp;

    - table_contents.rows.each do |row|
      %tr

        %td.action_column
          - if input_elements 
            = link_to '', '#', :class => 'sub_item_action inline_add', :tabindex => 999
            = link_to '', '#', :class => 'sub_item_action inline_delete', :tabindex => 999
          - else
            &nbsp;

        - row.all_cells.each do |cell|
          %td.content_column{ :class => "#{'no_data' if cell.no_data?}", 'data-column-id' => cell.id }
            - if input_elements 
              = text_field_tag "step[table_contents][][#{cell.id}]", cell.value, :onfocus =>"if(this.value=='Table Value...') this.value='';",:placeholder => 'Table Value...', :onblur => "if(this.value=='') this.value='Table Value...'", :disabled => cell.no_data?
            - else
              = h ParsedLine.new(cell.value).result

        %td &nbsp;
```

Comment: `.live` still works in 1.7.1. If the line "stopped working" then the error is somewhere else. Maybe you have to change the selector to `input[name*="element_name"]` (quote the value). Or there might be a problem in your event handler. Have a look at the console for errors and set breakpoints, step through your code and do some basic debugging.

Comment: have you tried with $('body').on instead of $(document).on?

Comment: Could you provide a JS fiddle?

Comment: I've had this problem with 1.71 too, try upgrading to 1.8, I did and it fixed my .on issues

Comment: Isn't `autocompletechange` part of jquery UI?  Did you upgrade that to a compatible version?

Comment: I did try $('body').on instead of $(document) and I also tried quoting "element_name", but neither worked. I am using JQuery-UI 1.8.6, which I believe should not be a problem.

Comment: We have to see your HTML to know what might be wrong with your selectors.